# C# Exporting interface as dll in an existing project with custom variable types

Tags: c#, plugins

I'm creating a project in which I made my own classes but now I need to support plugins. So I need an interface to then export as dll, so people can create plugins using that dll as the interface.
Now I'd like the plugin that is being created to be able to use my custom types.

For example:

My project has a class named Product.
I then created an interface with the following method:

```
Product[] getProducts();
```

Then a user that creates a plugin overrides that method and needs to have access to the Product class.
How am I going to do this?

I've tried to compile my whole project as a .dll but that just gives alot of errors.
I've also tried to compile the neccesary project files to a .dll but my project refers to almost every part so it still has errors.

I'd like to google it, but I've no idea what to google on.

Thanks.

**Edit:**
I'm using Visual C# 2013 express edition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a separate project that only contains interfaces.  Your main product would reference this assembly and the extensions would also reference this assembly.

For example, lets say you want extensions to provide a method GetAnimals() which returns an IEnumerable.  Your second project would contain an interface that looks like this:

```
public interface IAnimal
{
    UInt32 Height { get; }
}

public interface IExtension
{
    IEnumerable<IAnimal> GetAnimals();
}
```

The project would be of type class library and would only contain these interfaces.  The project would *not* reference your main project.  Your main project would reference this class library and you could give the class library to your users/customers/extenders and they could build extensions by implementing IExtension.

**Update:** A key in making extensions is that your users will never have direct access to any of your concrete types.  They will always only have access to the interfaces that your concrete types implement.  You will need to structure your application to have interface hierarchies for everything so that you can provide those interfaces to the user.  You want to avoid putting any concrete types into your extension class library.

Comment: ---- Nevermind my last comment. I think I understand it. Let me quickly test it and I'll accept your answer ;)

Comment: Aye, thanks. My test worked! Now I got to start rewriting ALOT xD

Comment: I don't know if you'll read this. But what if the plugin wants to request a method from the Main Project?

Comment: Presumably, the main application will need to instantiate a type in the plug-in.  If you want the plug-in to be able to call back into the main project, then the constructor for whatever type the main application instantiated would accept some ICallbacks.  ICallbacks would have methods that the plug-in might want to call on it and the implementation would be provided by the main application when the plug-in type is constructed.  Then the plug-in type can save ICallback and make calls on it whenever.